# Before QGraphicsItem::paint will be called

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsitem

I’m working on a project, where I use `QGraphicsScene`, `QGraphicsViwe`, `QGraphicsItem`. I want to do some calculations right before `QGraphicsItem::paint` will be called.

So is there a way to do something before `QGraphicsItem::paint`  will be called?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What difference would it make just to do it at the beginning of the `paint` function?

Comment: @cmannett85 - it has downsides, for example you will have to include it every time you implement the paintEvent. Sadly, there doesn't appear to be much alternatives. Maybe subclassing `QGraphicsScene`...

Comment: I can do that in `paint`, but it would be not effective, I must do the same thing every time when paint will be called. That's why I'm looking for another way.

Comment: Can't you just skip the calculations if they were already done by a previous call to paint (for example with a "dirty" flag) ?

Comment: Yes, that's a solution too!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QGraphicsView` has function `showEvent()` and if you override it you it will be called right before item's paint functions. You can get your scene by calling `scene()` function, after which you can get all items.